# C++: Why won't getline() print the last word of the input string?

Tags: c++, class, output, getline, istream

i'm trying to get my program to read a string and then output each word on an individual line. When I call this function it is not printing the last word of the sentence. I have not been able to find an answer to this problem.

For example:

> **Input:**
>
> Hello there my friend
>
> **Output:**
>
> Hello
>
> there
>
> my

Here is my code:

```
istream& operator >> (istream& in, FlexString& input) {
    std::string content;
    while (std::getline (in,content,' ')) {
        cout << content << endl;
    }

    return in;
}
```

I'm new to C++ so this may be dumb, but I tried adding another `cout` call to print *content* on the next line after the while loop but it won't print it for some reason.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://ideone.com/92ZTN7).

Comment: I tried running this in a test program and it is still printing the same result as before. The command-line appears to hang after printing the second-last word and doesn't appear to be finishing processing the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getline` didn't skip the last word. It's still waiting for you to finish it. You selected the space character (`' '`) as the delimiter, so getline is going to read until if finds a space (not a tab or a newline), or until the input stream ends. Your loop isn't going to stop at the end of the line either, like you seem to be expecting. It is going to keep reading until the stream ends.

If you want to read a single line, and then separate the line word by word, then just call `getline` once, with the `\n` delimiter (which is the default). Then use an `istringstream` to separate the resulting string word by word.

```
std::string line;
std::getline(in, line);
std::istringstreaam iss(line);
std::string content;
while (iss >> content)
    std::cout << content << std::endl;
```

Comment: Look at Kerreks comment. It is working on IDEone, so there must be something wrong with your argumentation (or it is some compiler specific thingy)

Comment: @tobi303: Of course it's working on IDEone. It's working on the OP's computer too. He just doesn't understand what getline does.

Comment: @tobi303: To be more clear, on IDEone, Kerrek is passing a single line to standard input, and then terminating it. `getline` stops reading at the termination. But for the OP, standard input is coming from the keyboard. He is (I guess) expecting it to be terminated when he hits the enter key, but it is not. It just continues to wait for him to type.

Comment: "error: expected primary-expression before ',' token std::getline(istream, line);" Oh I see now that I should use 'in' in place of 'istream'.

Comment: @CameronO'Reilly: Yes, the code assumes there is an `std::istream` in scope named `istream`. I changed it to match your code.

Comment: Thank you very very much for your assistance! I think I've got a better grasp of how getline() works. I have finally got it printing correctly. :)